# return max value for each group but when there is a tie, return one with lower id in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, max, greatest-n-per-group

I am using MySQL 8.0

My table looks like this:

```
group   user_id    score
  A        1        33
  B        2        22
  A        3        22
  B        4        22
```

I want it to return

```
group   user_id score
  A        1     33
  B        2     22
```

note that even though group B has same score user_id=2 is final winner since he/she has lower user_id

How to improve from below query...?

```
SELECT group, user_id, max(score)
  from table
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Note that GROUP is a reserved word in MySQL, making it a poor choice as a table/column identifier.

Comment: ah yup that was just an example group column is actually a different name, but thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Ambleu you are on the right track using `MAX()`, but to do this you need to use it in addition to `MIN()`, and also use a sub query to get the `MAX(score)` like this:

```
SELECT `mt`.`group`,
    MIN(`mt`.`user_id`) AS `user_id`,
    `mt`.`score`
FROM `myTable` AS `mt`
JOIN (SELECT `group`,
        MAX(`score`) AS `score`
      FROM `myTable`
      GROUP BY `group`) AS `der` ON `der`.`group` = `mt`.`group`
        AND `der`.`score` = `mt`.`score`
GROUP BY `mt`.`group`, `mt`.`score`
```

[Here are your tables and the solution query mocked up on db-fiddle.](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sCJoYTPz7vkGqesBwayTC7/1)

If this doesn't get you what you need please let me know and I'll try to assist further.

Comment: Amazing! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL 8.0, I would recommend window functions:

```
select grp, user_id, score
fom (
    select t.*, 
        row_number() over(partition by grp order by score desc, user_id) rn
    from mytable t
) t
where rn = 1
```

Alternatively, you can use a correlated subquery for filtering:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where user_id = (
    select t1.user_id
    from mytable t1
    where t1.grp = t.grp
    order by t1.score desc, t1.user_id limit 1
)
```

The second query would take advantage of an index on `(grp, score desc, user_id)`.

Side note: `group` is a language keyword, hence a poor choice for a column name. I renamed it to `grp` in the queries.

Comment: good idea to mention window functions, upvoted